# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List

Tags: java, xml, list, parsing, dom

Im using Jersey to build a REST Service and want to return a List as XML.
I dont know where this error is comming from , any idea about that guys ?

```
public class ProduitImportXml {

public static List<Produit> getProduits() {

    List<Produit> produitsList = new ArrayList<Produit>();

    try {   
         File inputFile = new File("ProduitData.xml");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("produits"); 
         for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
             Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el = (Element) nNode;
                NodeList childNodes = el.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0,len = nList.getLength();j<len; j++) {
                Produit p=new Produit(
              el.getElementsByTagName("idProduit").item(j).getTextContent(),
                produitsList.add(p);    
                        }
                    }
            }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return produitsList;
}
```

And i got the following console message :

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List
```